# Detecting the change on the certain column in the history table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Consider the following data:

```
history.data
=======================================
id |data_id| col1  | col2  | date
---+-------+-------+-------+-----------
1  |1      | 123   | 321   | 2017-08-01
2  |1      | 124   | 321   | 2017-08-03
3  |2      | 222   | 555   | 2017-08-05
4  |2      | 242   | 555   | 2017-08-07
5  |2      | 242   | 333   | 2017-08-11
```

So this is the `history_data` table where I keep all the changes in a certain table.
Right now I need to get the date of the last change for every present entry of `data` in the `col1` column.
In that case desired output should be

```
data_id | date
--------+-----------
1       | 2017-08-03
2       | 2017-08-07
```

I need to do this in the following context:

```
with cte1 as (
    select distinct on(data_id)
    data_id,
    date::date

    from data d
    join history.data hd on hd.data_id = d.id
    order by d.id, hd.date desc
)
```

So as you can see, for now I'm just getting the date of the last record change, regardless of on what column that change occured.

Could anyone please help me with that?

Comment: Why for `data_id=2` you expect date `2017-08-07` instead of  `2017-08-11` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze because on the `2017-08-11` the change had occured on the `col2`, but I'm interested in changes only on `col1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to get the previous `prev_col1` value and `prev_col1 <> col1` to identify all rows where a change occured:

```
select distinct on(data_id) * from (
    select lag(col1) over (partition by data_id order by d.id) prev_col1,
    d.id,
    col1,
    data_id,
    date::date
    from data d
    join history.data hd on hd.data_id = d.id
) t where prev_col1 <> col1 or prev_col1 is null
order by id desc
```

The `prev_col1 is null` condition is needed for groups with only 1 member per `data_id` and assumes that the first member qualifies as a change.

Answer (score 1):

```
select data_id, max(mindt) from (
    select data_id, col1, min(date) as mindt
    from history_data
    group by data_id, col1
) t
group by data_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
select distinct on(data_id)
       data_id,
       col1
from data d
join history_data hd on d.id = hd.data_id
order by data_id, date desc;
```

to get the *last* `col1` value per `data_id`:

```
data_id col1
-------------
1   124
2   242
```

Using the above query as a derived table you can join back to the original table to get the *earliest* date for each group:

```
select t1.data_id, t1.col1, min(date::date)
from history_data t1
join (
   select distinct on(data_id)
          data_id,
          col1
   from data d
   join history_data hd on d.id = hd.data_id
   order by data_id, date desc
) t2 on t1.data_id = t2.data_id and t1.col1 = t2.col1
group by t1.data_id, t1.col1;
```

**Output:**

```
data_id col1    min
---------------------------
1       124     03.08.2017 
2       242     07.08.2017
```

**Note:** The query will also return `data_id` groups related to *just one* `col1` value. You need to change the query slightly to filter these rows out, in case you don't need them.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/EBP5888)